# Terminate the execution of web api request in Initialize function

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am working on some Restful APIs in .net web api . All the API controllers that I am working on inherit from a base API controller. It has some logic in the Initialize function.

```
protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
{
// some logic
}
```

There is a new product requirement comes in and I want to return the response to the client in the Initialize function depending on some criteria.
e.g.

```
 protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
{
// some logic
   controllerContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "error");

}
```

however it seems like that the .net pipeline still moves on even I return the response already.

Is there anyway to return the response inside that function and stop the execution? Or I have to refactor the existing code to do it in another way?

Comment: try calling Response.End or Application.CompleteRequest()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a hacky way of accomplishing what you want. Throw an exception like so.

```
protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
{
       // some logic
       if(youhavetosend401)
           throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
}
```

The cleaner way, assuming what you are trying to do is all about authorization is to create an authorization filter like so.

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext context)
    {
        // Do your stuff and determine if the request can proceed further or not
        // If not, return false
        return true;
    }
}
```

Apply the filter on the action method or controller or even globally.

```
[MyAuthorize]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
{
     return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpResponseException to send the HttpResponseMessage created for Error.

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
{ 
   //Your Logic
   throw new HttpResponseException(controllerContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "error"));
   base.Initialize(controllerContext);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use
    Application.CompleteRequest()
it will fire the EndRequest event.

Comment: This is a bad idea. I don't think this stops the MVC pipeline from continuing so the requested action will still run it just won't return a result to the user. If you use this for authorization you are allowing unauthorized users to execute protected code.

Comment: Using AuthorizeAttribute as the accepted answer suggests is the proper way to handle this scenario.